# Как в классе-наследнике вызвать сеттер родительского класса (JS)?

Tags: javascript, класс

Как в дочернем классе вызвать сеттер родительского класса (JS)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос. Вообще через `parent`. Можете показать пример и результат которого хотите добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set iin(value) {
  super.iin = value;
  // more code
}
```

```js
class Base {
  set iin(value) {
    console.log("Base.iin setter", value);
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  set iin(value) {
    super.iin = value;
    console.log("Child.iin setter", value);
  }
}

var a = new Child();
a.iin = 123;
```

Comment: ................

Comment: да, все работает. Я вызывал сеттер родителя как функцию, я и думал, что нужно сделать присваиванием, но не попробовал, что то засомневался. Общем СПАСИБО!

Comment: @Aleksey Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.